# How to convert int eg.99 to char?

Tags: c

How to achieve the same result as this below. I want to add values to char[] using int values.

```
int i;
char c;

i = 99; /* ASCII DEC 'c' */
c = i;  /* 'c'*/
```

Comment: What's the error? This looks fine.

Comment: [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/), [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

Comment: Where's your `char[]`? I only see a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, characters are represented as small integers having values based on the machine's character set.  (Indeed, it's hard to imagine any other representation.)  So you can pretty freely intermix integers and characters.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[10];
    a[0] = 72;
    a[1] = 101;
    a[2] = 108;
    a[3] = 108;
    a[4] = 111;
    a[5] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

This code prints "`Hello`", and you can pretty easily determine why.  (Make sure you also understand why the final assignment `a[5] = 0` is absolutely necessary.)

(Obviously this wouldn't work on a machine with an [unusual character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), but such machines are quite rare.)

This example, "in the other direction" so to speak, may also be instructive:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o');
}
```

Comment: Answers the question, but I hope nobody ever does this for real.  ;)

Comment: @jdc not a fan of the ioccc?

Comment: @jdc I'm not sure about the OP, but many beginners have been crippled by languages such as BASIC with their quaint and unnecessary `INT$` and `CHR$` operators.  Examples like this, blasphemous though they indeed look to someone well-versed in C, are a necessary interim step to cure beginners of their BASIC disease.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I'm a fan of the IOCCC insofar as much as I'm amazed at what people can actually have the patience to come up with!

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes, and realizing that char's are integral types is important too.  Still, seeing a character literal like 'c' would be enough to cure me.

Comment: The '0' is indicator of end of the string, but what about '\0'.

Comment: @BozhidarManev `0` and `'\0'` are exactly the same, just like `65` and `'A'` are the same, and 32 and `'0'` are the same.  (But `'0'` and `'\0'` are not the same.)  It might have been better style to set the end of the string using `a[5] = '\0'` -- but then again, it would have been better style to set the beginning of the string with `a[0] = 'H'` !

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks for the quick response. So i guess that hex and binary would work the same way as dec, right.  According to D. Ritchie's book "C language" the "right way" to end a string is '\0'.

Comment: @BozhidarManev Yes.  You could equally well end the string with `a[5] = 0`, `a[5] = '\0'`, `a[5] = 0x00`, `a[5] = 000`, or `a[5] = 1-1`.